# [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: Failed to load component ([APP]). Original error: Manifest not found for component id [ID] and version "17.0.2"

Tags: web-parts, spfx-extension

I am getting an error when testing the Web Part on workbench.aspx using **gulp serve** command

Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
Failed to load component "f02eed6e-bebc-426e-9938-xxxxxxx" ([APP-NAME]). Original error: Manifest not found for component id "aa0a46ec-1505-43cd-a44a-93f3a5aa460a" and version "17.0.2".

INNERERROR:
Manifest not found for component id "aa0a46ec-1505-43cd-a44a-93f3a5aa460a" and version "17.0.2".
CALLSTACK:
Error
at t [as constructor] (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_0d974feb82adaa817c93d235f081873b.js:3:208866)
at new t (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_0d974feb82adaa817c93d235f081873b.js:70:674444)
at e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_0d974feb82adaa817c93d235f081873b.js:70:711728)
at e.buildLoadComponentError (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_0d974feb82adaa817c93d235f081873b.js:70:707819)
at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.systemjs-component-loader_en-us_54faa0ae3793669d4a62.js:1:6036

Noticed that component aa0a46ec-1505-43cd-a44a-93f3a5aa460a belongs to react, currenctly the manifest shows two versions 17.0.1 and 17.0.2 as they are dependencies for other components

package.json as follows:

```json
{
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxt",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0"
    },
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "gulp bundle",
        "clean": "gulp clean",
        "test": "gulp test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@coveo/headless": "2.10.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
        "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
        "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "^1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.16.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.12",
        "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.199.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "tslib": "2.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.5": "0.2.2",
        "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.16.1",
        "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.16.1",
        "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
        "ajv": "^6.12.5",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.2",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4"
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Tried updating react to 17.0.2 and delete node_modules and doing npm install again. Deleted package-lock.json without any success